# Get information clientid connect and disconnect

Tags: mosquitto

My project, using mosquitto is mqtt server.

I want to get the information clientid once it connects or disconnects to server. Then it will automatically send to sub default. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Please show us what you have done? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want some other client to know when a certain client connects to the broker,

When your client connects , maybe in onConnected(depends on the client library) handle you can have a specific message published with connectin info. Which the listening client can be subscribed to.

Whereas for disconnection, try the last will message. To quote mosquitto.org

> **Last Will and Testament**
>
> The last will and testament or just “will” is a very nice feature of MQTT. When your client connects to the MQTT broker/server, it can give the broker this will, which consists of a topic and a message. If the client is disconnected from the broker unexpectedly, that is to say without sending a disconnect message, then the broker publishes the will message on the will topic.